# Why use the same IDXGIFactory for Device and Swap Chain

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, dxgi

The reference of the [IDXGIFactory interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174535(v=vs.85).aspx) tells me, that in order to create a swap chain, I might use the same factory that was used to create the Direct3D device:

> Because you can create a Direct3D device without creating a swap chain, you might need to retrieve the factory that is used to create the device in order to create a swap chain.

It also gives the following code exmaple:

```
IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&pDXGIDevice);

IDXGIAdapter * pDXGIAdapter;
hr = pDXGIDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void **)&pDXGIAdapter);

IDXGIFactory * pIDXGIFactory;
pDXGIAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void **)&pIDXGIFactory);
```

The article is very spare and when trying to fully understand it, the following two questions arose, whereas the first question is the main question (concerning the title of this thread):

Why do I have to use the same factory that was used to create the Direct3D device in order to create the swap chain? Does the factory instance maintain an internal state which is important or is it just to avoid to create another instance of the factory which consumes resources?

Also, within the code sample I struggle with the following line of code:

```
hr = pDXGIDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void **)&pDXGIAdapter);
```

To me, it is not logical, that the IDXGIAdapter is the the parent of the IDXGIDevice. Otherwise I would expect the [IDXGIAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174523(v=vs.85).aspx) to have a method like CreateDevice which would make the adapter the parent of the device. But that is not the case. Why is the adapter the parent of the device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root of the problem goes back to DXGI 1.0 (Direct3D 10) and DXGI 1.1 (Direct3D 11). If you tried to use a `IDXGIFactory` created by both `CreateDXGIFactory` and `CreateDXGIFactory1` in the same process, things would go pear-shaped pretty quick.

The other issue is that there's an implicit factory created when you use the 'default device' with Direct3D 10.x or 11.x device creation. The 'magic code sequence' above lets you get the factory created implicitly.

The second step in the docs should be `dxgiDevice->GetAdapter` not `dxgiDevice->GetParent`. I'll file a doc bug on that.

This is even easier to do if using `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`:

```
    // First, retrieve the underlying DXGI Device from the D3D Device
    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice1> dxgiDevice;
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(m_d3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice));

    // Identify the physical adapter (GPU or card) this device is running on.
    ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> dxgiAdapter;
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(dxgiAdapter.GetAddressOf()));

    // And obtain the factory object that created it.
    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory1> dxgiFactory;
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), &dxgiFactory));
```

**Direct3D 12**

Note that this whole area has been cleaned up with Direct3D 12, and you can't use QI to get an `IDXGIDevice` from a `ID3D12Device`.

**References**

[DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI): Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025.aspx)
[Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Chuck, for your detailed answer. But isn't the implicit factory created for a "default adapter" (dxgiAdapter->GetParent(...))? The point with Direct3D 12 is a little confusing: Will there be an explicit method to get the IDXGIDevice from the ID3D12Device?

Comment: For Direct3D 12 you just create the DXGI factory directly and use that to enumerate adapters if needed. See [DeviceResources](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d12game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp). If you have the Direct3D 12 device, you cat get an adapter "LUID" for it, then go scan the DXGI enumeration list to find a match.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Chuck Walbourn's comment on how to get a DXGI Factory from a **D3D12** Device, here is a possible implementation:

```cpp
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <dxgi1_6.h>
#include <wrl/client.h>
#include <concepts>
#include <expected>

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

template <typename TFactory> requires std::derived_from<TFactory, IDXGIFactory>
std::expected<ComPtr<TFactory>, HRESULT> GetDXGIFactoryFromDevice(ID3D12Device* device)
{
    ComPtr<TFactory> foundFactory;

    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    // Get the adapter LUID (locally unique identifier) associated with the D3D device
    const LUID adapterLuid = device->GetAdapterLuid();

    // Create DXGI factory for adapter enumeration
    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> enumFactory;
    if (FAILED(hr = CreateDXGIFactory1(IID_PPV_ARGS(&enumFactory)))) return std::unexpected(hr);

    // Enumerate DXGI adapters to find adapter with the matching LUID
    for (UINT adapterIndex = 0u; ; ++adapterIndex)
    {
        ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter1;
        if (FAILED(hr = enumFactory->EnumAdapters1(adapterIndex, &adapter1)))
        {
            if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) break; // No more adapters to enumerate
            return std::unexpected(hr); // Error
        }

        DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 desc;
        if (FAILED(hr = adapter1->GetDesc1(&desc))) return std::unexpected(hr);

        if (desc.AdapterLuid.LowPart == adapterLuid.LowPart &&
            desc.AdapterLuid.HighPart == adapterLuid.HighPart)
        {
            // Found the matching adapter.
            // Get the DXGI interface from the adapter
            if (FAILED(hr = adapter1->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&foundFactory)))) return std::unexpected(hr);
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundFactory;
}
```

This allows querying for different interface versions of the DXGI factory and provides basic error handling.

It can be changed to just fetch the DXGI adapter from the device as well of course.